# For Couchbase Lite, use QueryBuilder to query on a property that is inside a nested JSON

Tags: ios, swift, couchbase-lite

I am new to Couchbase Lite so might be asking a really basic question. I have a requirement where I need to use the `QueryBuilder` to fetch the data at a property which is nested inside another property. Seems like a pretty straight forward nested query thing but I'm not able to find resources for the same. Consider the following example where I have multiple documents that follow the same document pattern:

```
{
  "user":{
    "id": 1,
    "metadata": {
      "anotherId": 2,
      "aRandomArray": [
        "Works",
        "WorksAsWell"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, how will the QueryBuilder's query look like if I have to make the query for the following use-cases:

1. Fetch a document where `id` is equal to **1**
2. Fetch a document `anotherId` is equal to **2**
3. Fetch a document where `aRandomArray` contains **WorksAsWell**

So the question primarily revolves around how to create a query for properties that are nested inside other properties using QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by the Couchbase team on their forum: https://www.couchbase.com/forums/t/use-querybuilder-to-query-on-a-property-that-is-inside-a-nested-json/37295/2?u=shubham.bakshi